# Remover Row DataTable por ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

É possível remover uma linha do datatable pelo id? É que tenho uma modal de confirmação perguntando se o usuário deseja deletar. Caso clicar em sim, ele chama uma função de delete.

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var data = $(e.relatedTarget).data();
    $('.btn-ok', this).data('recordId', data.recordId);
    $('#message_confirm_delete').html(data.message);
});
$('#confirm-delete').on('click', '.btn-ok', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('recordId');
    $('#confirm-delete').modal('hide');
    $.deleta2(id);
});
$.deleta2 = function (id) {
    var data_table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable();
    console.log(data_table);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto resolveu...

```
var data_table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable();
data_table.row($('#item_'+id)).remove().draw();
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar métodos para manipular a tabela como abaixo:

```
let tab_methods = {
    getline: (table, column, value) => {
        table.rows()[0].forEach((item) => {
            if(tabela.row(item).data()[column] == value) 
                return tabela.row(item);
        });
    },
    delete: (selector, column, value) => {
        let table = $(selector).DataTable();
        let row = tab_methods.getline(table, column, value);
        row.remove().draw();
    }
}
```

Dessa forma você terá métodos genéricos que você poderá declará globalmente e reutilizar por toda a aplicação. O uso fica assim:

```
tab_methods.delete("#may_table", 0, 12);
```

Dá para desenvolver mais métodos ou quem sabe uma mine biblioteca para a sua aplicação no quesito manipular tabelas. alem de resolver o problema é um ótimo exercício.